# ¿Còmo consultar en MySQL para que me devuelva un nombre a partir de un codigo?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla llamada `user` que tiene códigos únicos y nombres asociados a él.
ejemplo:

```
COdigo         Nombre
[137,221]       Jose Perez
[127,241]       Juan Gomez
```

y quiero consultar por el codigo que me devuelva el nombre como seria la consulta intento algo asi pero no me funciona

```
SELECT nombre FROM user WHERE UID=[137,221];
```

nota los codigos vienen con [] y separados por , porque es un dato proveniente de un sensor

Comment: al estar usando corchetes `[]` seguro que ese campo es de tipo `VARCHAR` por lo que en tu consulta así como la tienes pasa esto entre comillas `UID="[137,221]";` ya con eso lograrás obtener lo que buscas de tu consulta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te hacen falta los identificadores de texto para el ID.

```
SELECT nombre FROM user WHERE UID='[137,221]';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo así (usando PDO):

```
try{
$dbnames= "tubasededatos";
$host="tuhost";
$user="usuariodelabd";
$pass="passdeluser";
$tabla="nombretabla";

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$dbnames;host=$host";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$ssql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE UID='[127,241]'";
$rs = $pdo->prepare($ssql);
$rs->execute();
while ($fila = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    foreach($fila as $row){
     echo "Nombre de usuario: ".$row['Nombre'];
   }
}
}catch(PDOException $error){
    echo 'Error de conexión: ' . $error;
    echo "Se ha producido un error y no se han podido bajar los datos de la BD.";
}
```

Esto devolvería:

> Nombre de usuario: Juan Gomez

Comment: Sería mejor si usaras parámetros en tu ejemplo para mostrar como evitar inyección de SQL.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, lo puse rápido y obvié la parte de los parámetros. De todas formas, en este caso concreto, como no hay un input por parte del usuario, si no que lo está buscando directamente, no creo que pueda haber problemas con inyecciones.